# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower' python

Tags: python

My abc.txtfile looks like this

```
Mary    Kom     28 F
Emon    Chatterje  32 M
Sunil   Singh  35 M
```

Now i am getting the desired result with the following traceback:Please help me out. I am not getting where am i going wrong

```
Enter for Search Criteria
1.FirstName  2.LastName  3.Age  4.Gender  5.Exit 1
Enter FirstName :m
Mary Kom 28 F
Emon Chatterje 32 M
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "testcode.py", line 50, in <module>
    if (records.searchFName(StringSearch)):
  File "testcode.py", line 12, in searchFName
    return matchString.lower() in self.fname.lower()
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

My Code:

```
#!usr/bin/python
import sys

class Person:
    def __init__(self, firstname=None, lastname=None, age=None, gender=None):
        self.fname = firstname
        self.lname = lastname
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender
    def searchFName(self, matchString):

        return matchString.lower() in self.fname.lower()

    def searchLName(self, matchString):

        return matchString.lower() in self.lname.lower()

    def searchAge(self, matchString):

        return str(matchString) in self.age

    def searchGender(self, matchString):

        return matchString.lower() in self.gender.lower()

    def display(self):

        print self.fname, self.lname, self.age, self.gender


f= open("abc","r")
list_of_records = [Person(*line.split()) for line in f]
f.close()
found = False
n=0

n1 = raw_input("Enter for Search Criteria\n1.FirstName  2.LastName  3.Age  4.Gender      5.Exit " )

if n1.isdigit():
    n = int(n1)
else:
    print "Enter Integer from given"
    sys.exit(1)
if n == 0 or n>5:
    print "Enter valid search "
if n == 1:
    StringSearch = raw_input("Enter FirstName :")
    for records in list_of_records:
        if (records.searchFName(StringSearch)):
            found = True
            records.display()

    if not found:
        print "No matched record"

if n == 2:
    StringSearch = raw_input("Enter LastName :")
    for records in list_of_records:
        if records.searchLName(StringSearch):
            found = True
            records.display()

   if not found:
        print "No matched record"

if n == 3:
    StringSearch = raw_input("Enter Age :")
    if (StringSearch.isdigit()):
        StringSearch1 = int(StringSearch)
    else:
        print "Enter Integer"
        sys.exit()
    for records in list_of_records:
        if records.searchAge(StringSearch):
            found = True
        records.display()

    if not found:
        print "No matched record"

if n == 4:
    StringSearch = raw_input("Enter Gender(M/F) :")
    for records in list_of_records:
        if records.searchGender(StringSearch):
           found = True
           records.display()
    if not found:
        print "No matched record"

if n == 5:
    sys.exit(1)
```

Please help solve my problrm to where am i going wrong ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a `Person()` class with no `firstname`. You created it from an empty line in your file:

```
list_of_records = [Person(*line.split()) for line in f]
```

An empty line results in an empty list:

```
>>> '\n'.split()
[]
```

which leads to `Person(*[])` being called, so a `Person()` instance was created with no arguments, leaving the default `firstname=None`.

Skip empty lines:

```
list_of_records = [Person(*line.split()) for line in f if line.strip()]
```

You may also want to default to empty strings, or specifically test for `None` values before treating attributes as strings:

```
def searchFName(self, matchString):
    return bool(self.fname) and matchString.lower() in self.fname.lower()
```

Here `bool(self.fname)` returns `False` for empty or `None` values, giving you a quick `False` return value when there is no first name to match against:

```
>>> p = Person()
>>> p.fname is None
True
>>> p.searchFName('foo')
False
```

Comment: how come my attributes would return none. i am passing an argument but ??

Comment: @johnjohn: No, you are not doing that when the line is empty. An empty line results in: `Person(*[])`, which is the same as `Person()`.

Comment: there is no empty line in my file too

Comment: moreovere my list_of_records contains the list object of the data in my abc file. so each record is an object which is an list

Comment: @johnjohn: Yes, you do. Check again, the *last line* is probably empty. That is the **only** way you get a `None` value here. Your `list_of_records` list contains `Person()` objects, not lists. Can you please try out the code I propose?

Comment: i tried your code and it worked. but i am not getting to how i am getting an line empty ? still not clear.

Comment: Because you have an empty line in your input file. But you won't believe me, apparently.

Comment: i dont say i dont believe you. i am just confused to how there can be an empty line in my input file

Comment: @johnjohn: If the last line in your input file is empty, it won't be that immediately obvious in your text editor; after all, that last empty line just looks like the end of the file.

Comment: ok ..ok.. i got it. there was an empty line in my file at last. now can u tell me why that empty line creatd an problem , imean where it would create the problem ?

Comment: @johnjohn: Read my answer carefully. `line.split()` creates an empty list if `line` only contains whitespace, I demonstrate that in my post. An empty line results in an empty list, and you thus call `Person(*[])`; that means you are applying 0 arguments to `Person()`. That leaves *all* keyword arguments to their default values, `firstname=None, lastname=None, age=None, gender=None` are all left set to `None`.